# Zeno's Paradoxes Graph with Latex (half circles, arcs and spirals)

Tags: graphics, geometry

I am pretty new to Latex and wanted to know how would go about to create the following graphic or something similar (only interested in geometrical aspect, not the turtles and achilles) with Tikz or Tkz-euclide[image: Zeno's paradoxes].

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c);
  \def\firststep{3cm}
  \foreach \step in {1,...,5}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mypow{2^\step}
    % Achille
    \draw[blue,fill=blue!10] (c) arc(180:0:\firststep/\mypow) coordinate(c);
    % Turtle
    \draw[red,fill=red!10]  (c) arc(-180:0:\firststep/\mypow/2);
  }
  \draw[green] (0,0) -- (\firststep * 2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for, Paul Gaborit.